# Images dont work on my HTML! Can someone explain whats wrong?

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Poka.css" type="text/css">
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title> Pokaface Portfolio  </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <img src="/Images/VancouverClouds.png" alt="BackgroundImage" style="width:128px;height:128px" />
         <nav>
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">About Me</a>
            <a href="">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
         </nav>
         <h1>
            <span>POKAFACE</span>
         </h1>
         <p class="catch-phrase">
            TWO SIDES TO A STORY
         </p>
         <p class="kicker">
            WEB-DESIGN//PHOTOGRAPHY//VIDEOGRAPHY
         </p>
      </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've done everything to upload my images but it doesn't work

Comment: check the image path

Comment: Hey, i did that and i did it with different images. The result was still bad.

Comment: try not using capslock in image name or extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's the capital I. Try using src="images/VancouverClouds.png"

Answer (score 0):

If it's your index file, then remove `/` from your image path and if it's an internal page then add `..` before `/`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/Images/VancouverClouds.png" alt="BackgroundImage" style="width:128px;height:128px" />
```

use

If images folder is under your application folder  use `"~"`(Relative Path)

```
<img src="~/Images/VancouverClouds.png" alt="BackgroundImage" style="width:128px;height:128px" />
```

If it is outside of your application folder you need to use Full image path

Hope this helps